# SSL offloading with load balancer

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ssl

I have configured an application where the load balancer will do an ssl offloading, all request from will come to https://application.com and it will internally redirect to apache port 80. I have saml configured with shibboleth in apache and it expects its destination URL as https. As apache always get the request on port 80 it is creating problem. It is complaining the destination expected is https://application.com but got http://applcation.com is there a way in apache to give the server name as https in apache, I tried using canonical name but no luck.

I set as below in my configuration

```
ServerName https://application.com
UseCanonicalName On
```

Please let me know if there is any other way to set this.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you set up an ssl vhost for shibboleth and use it ? You can go for selfsigned certificates for your ssl connection between webserver and LB.